# Logging for application in different environment Log4j

Tags: deployment, logging, configuration, log4j

I am developing a logging framework using Log4j. I am not able to figure out how to maintain separate log files for different environment, i.e., development, testing, staging and production.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly you'll need a different copy of your log4j.xml for each environment.

Lets call it log4j-dev.xml, log4j-test.xml, log4j-stage.xml and log4j-prod.xml  each having their own settings like log file name and log levels.

You then pass in the corresponding file at the the server startup as a system property like below -

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-dev.xml
```

[This URL](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) has the example on how to pass this for Tomcat. The concept is the same for whichever server you are deploying on.

Comment: Like @Daniel said in their comment, we had to use -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j-dev.xml on an Amazon Linux AMI (Centos) when using log4j v2.13.3

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, I have used `"set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2-dev.xml"` instead of `log4j.configuration`

Comment: this als works for log4j2 with spring boot on our environments. `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2-dev.xml`

Comment: worth mentioning that this is only relevant if you are using Apache Tomcat