# How to make Log4j environment specific

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, logback-groovy

I am trying to edit my logging configuration file so that the levels for the logs would be different based on either it is in a development environment or production environment for example

in dev would be

```
<logger name="1" level="debug"/>
<logger name="2" level="debug"/>
<logger name="3" level="debug"/>
```

in production the loggers should be

```
<logger name="1" level="warn"/>
<logger name="2" level="warn"/>
<logger name="3" level="warn"/>
```

is there a way to do this with an environment variable and condition statement?
I want to try to avoid having a log file specific to each environment

Comment: Normally you have different files for each environment, and either you rename it in your build+deployment script, or you select it at startup, as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120446/logging-for-application-in-different-environment-log4j

Comment: so there is no way to do an if statement stating if the environment is whatever?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use two configuration files for logback, one that would log at least `debug` level and the other that would log at least `warning`.
Quote from [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html):

> 1. Logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
> 2. If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called
>      logback-test.xml in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the
>      classpath..

There is actually 4 and 5, but this is enough for the explanation.
So basically use `logback-test.xml` for dev, and `logback.xml` for prod. Of course, don't deploy `logback-test.xml` to prod.